# Using Visual Studio macro names to launch external applications doesn't work?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, arguments, macros

Using Visual Studio / C#, I've been debugging some nunit tests recently, and am now trying to make sure that if we branch the code that the unit tests don't stop working in debug mode.

I have this working by changing project properties to launch NUnit as an external program:

```
C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.8\bin\nunit-console.exe
```

..and then set my .nunit config:

```
D:\SomePath\branches\NewFeatureBranch\TestDSP.nunit
```

So now I'd like to make that path generic. I thought something like this should work:

```
$(SolutionDir)\$(ProjectName).nunit
```

...but NUnit exits before running the test. Those variables don't appear to get sent though as a quick console app tells me:

```
arg[0] = D:\Projects\Tools\ArgDebugger\Debug\ArgDebugger.exe
arg[1] = $(SolutionDir)\$(ProjectName).nunit
```

Is there another way I can feed that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when I build two console apps.

App2 is debugged with App1. In App1 System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() gives

*Solution\Project\Bin\Debug* of App2.

Therefore putting *..\..\..\* into the Working Directory of App2 gives me

*Solution\* of App2. So you can then change the path to the .nunit file to be *./TestDSP.nunit*

Comment: That's certainly an option - thanks. Still feels slightly cludgy, but definitely better than hardcoded paths!

Comment: As long as your paths are relative hardcoded, having many branches or copies of one branch will work.

Comment: I agree; it will definitely work for my current project structure :-)